# Ricoh scan to folder error "Authentication with the destination has failed"

Tags: printer

When scanning to folder I get the following error on a Ricoh Aficio MP C3002

> "Authentication with the destination has failed. Check settings. To
>   check the current status, press [Scanned Files Status]"

Answer (score 1):

When scanning to folder I get the following error on a Ricoh Aficio MP C3002

```
"Authentication with the destination has failed. Check settings. To check the current status, press [Scanned Files Status]"
```

On Windows 10:

1- Go to the Control Panel

2- Press on Programs and Features

3- Open Turn Windows features on or off

4- Check the box SMB 1.0/CIFS File Sharing Support

5- Install it and then restart your pc.

Comment: For other models, check this list - if you're not listed, you're likely not supported (exluding the newly-released IMC range, they're all fine.)

https://www.ricoh.com/products/mfp20170727_1.html

Answer (score 0):

Presuming this is Scan-to-Folder, the credentials saved on the copier are likely out of date, usually because the account used has had a password change.

This can be set in two places; either within the address book entry for that destination, or less likely applied generally to the machine:

**Logging in to make changes**

1. Open the web interface for the copier
2. In the top-right corner, click 'Login'.

[image: Login button]

3. Enter your credentials (by default, 'admin' with no password).

[image: The login prompt]

**Changing the credentials on a specific destination.**

1. Under Device Management, select Address Book.

[image: Address book]

2. Once loaded, select the radio button next to the relevant entry, then select Change.

[image: Selecting and changing address book entry]

3. In the Authentication Information section, by Folder Authentication, enter the Login User Name and select Change.

[image: Folder Authentication]

4. Enter the password when prompted and select OK.
5. **Click OK again on the Change User screen to save.** If you don't, it won't stick.

[image: Click OK or be sad]

**Changing the default credentials**

1. Under Device Management, select Configuration.

[image: Getting to config menu]

2. In the Device Settings section, select File Transfer.

[image: File Transfer option]

3. Next to SMB (if you're using Scan-to-Folder) or FTP, put in the username you wish to use, then click the relevant Change button to enter a password.

[image: Entering credentials]

4. Enter your password when prompted, then click 'OK'.
5. **Click OK on File Transfer screen to save**, otherwise the change will not apply.

Comment: i'll try again, but the password is new and it was not changed

Comment: In that case, this may be an issue with folder permissions or possibly SMB support - https://www.ricoh.com/products/mfp20170727_1.html

Comment: Check the scanner has read/write permissions on the folder. Also, in the case of Win10, make sure SMB v1 is enabled (via Control Panel > Programs & Features > Windwos features).

Answer (score 0):

“Authentication with the destination has failed. Check settings. To check the current status, press [Comm. Status/Print].”

Answer: You must choose connect Port SSL :465 , NO port 25 Default

it will ok .

Answer (score 0):

The error message - Ricoh scan to folder error “Authentication with the destination has failed” is always a major issue with Ricoh Scanner/Copier and it just requires a bunch of logical steps to get over the problem.

Your detailed directions above were a major life saver.

I had major issue with scanning to folder for Ricoh MPC2004 after I upgraded to Windows 10 on all my computers.

I just could not figure it out for almost two years.

But once I Check the box SMB 1.0/CIFS File Sharing Support and restarted my computer I was able to scan to folder.

It is highly important to utilize the browse network and connection test successfully to test that the network connection is correct before you can be sure everything is done properly.

Thanks!